# Blazor WASM URL routing

Tags: c#, .net, url, blazor, webassembly

I'm trying to create a file sharing webservice. For various reasons I need to implement it to work as follows:
url parameters are passed which identify the file for example: mysite.com/myfile/randomid

These urls are sent via e-mail to the specific file. So the end-user receives mysite.com/asdfg/12345 and clicks on it.

I created the site, published it and it is working properly, except that you must open the index page in order to get wasm to work and serve the page, instead of returning 404.

I have found it in the MSDN docs that this is the proper Blazor WASM functionality, under the section "Rewrite URLs for correct routing".
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0

But I couldn't find a workaround to let my users download the WASM application even if they only ever click on the link that has been sent out.

The website is hosted on a Synology NAS with the native Web Station package.

Is there a way to include it so no matter what url is called the webserver will serve the whole wasm application?

Comment: Are they just downloading the file or getting a Blazor info page with a download link. If just downloading, why not just send them to an API endpoint on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Create custom `404.html` which will be just a copy of the `index.html`.
Ideally do this using some sort of ci/cd pipeline. For example this works while using github actions:

```
    - name: copy index.html to 404.html
      run: cp ${{env.PUBLISH_DIR}}/wwwroot/index.html ${{env.PUBLISH_DIR}}/wwwroot/404.html
```